# why does the word "and" make MySQL full-text search so slow?

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search, codeigniter-3

I've written a CodeIgniter class to do a search of four db tables for some search string. These searches use [MySQL Natural Language Full-Text Search](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html). The SQL that actually performs the search is utilized as a prepared statement. This is what the SQL looks like, with the named parameter **:clean_string** getting replaced by the quoted string to be searched and the other named params being replaced by integers to weight the respective tables according to their importance:

```
SELECT c_i, c_t, seo_title, SUM(score) AS score
FROM (

SELECT c.id_code AS c_i, c.title AS c_t, c.seo_title, (MATCH(title) AGAINST (:clean_string IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)) * :career_title_factor AS score, 'q_ct' AS qid
FROM careers c
WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST (:clean_string IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)

UNION

SELECT c.id_code AS c_i, c.title AS c_t, c.seo_title, AVG(MATCH(ts.task) AGAINST (:clean_string IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)) * :career_task_statement_factor AS score, 'q_ts' AS qid
FROM tasks ts, careers c
WHERE ts.id_code = c.id_code
    AND MATCH(ts.task) AGAINST (:clean_string IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
GROUP BY c_i

UNION

SELECT c.id_code AS c_i, c.title AS c_t, c.seo_title, AVG(MATCH(oat.alternate_title) AGAINST (:clean_string IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)) * :career_alternate_title_factor AS score, 'q_at' AS qid
FROM other_titles oat, careers c
WHERE oat.id_code = c.id_code
    AND MATCH(oat.alternate_title) AGAINST (:clean_string IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
GROUP BY c_i

UNION

SELECT c.id_code AS c_i, c.title AS c_t, c.seo_title, AVG(MATCH(od.description) AGAINST (:clean_string IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)) * :career_occupation_data_factor AS score, 'q_od' AS qid
FROM other_data od, careers c
WHERE od.id_code = c.id_code
    AND MATCH(od.description) AGAINST (:clean_string IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
GROUP BY c_i

) AS union_query
GROUP BY c_i
```

This query runs nice and fast for most searches -- or even randomly generated nonsense strings. HOWEVER, it runs *extremely slow* when the word **and** appears in my search string. **Why is this happening?**

To demonstrate this, I have turned off MySQL query caching and run this test code:

```
public function test() {
    $new_elapsed = 0;

    $search_terms = array(
        "video games",
        "game video",
        "software",
        "nautical architect",
        "CEO",
        "pig and blanket machine",
        "art gallery",
        "rock and roll",
        "guitar god magic metal",
        "mott the hoople"
    );


    for($i=0; $i<10; $i++) {
        $search = $search_terms[$i];
        echo "search term is $search\n";

        $start = microtime(true);

        $results_new = MY_search::search_new($this->db, $search);
        $new_elapsed = (microtime(true) - $start);
        echo "new has " . sizeof($results_new) . " matches\n";
        echo "new_elapsed: $new_elapsed\n";

        echo "--\n";
    }
}
```

As you can see from the search results here, the two test queries with the word **and** in them run a LOT slower. Like a hundred times slower.

```
search term is video games
new has 76 matches
new_elapsed: 0.23601198196411
--
search term is game video
new has 73 matches
new_elapsed: 0.27281093597412
--
search term is software
new has 124 matches
new_elapsed: 0.41503596305847
--
search term is nautical architect
new has 24 matches
new_elapsed: 0.11621713638306
--
search term is CEO
new has 2 matches
new_elapsed: 0.012537002563477
--
search term is pig and blanket machine
new has 1078 matches
new_elapsed: 19.989203929901
--
search term is art gallery
new has 53 matches
new_elapsed: 0.19855809211731
--
search term is rock and roll
new has 1077 matches
new_elapsed: 16.845540046692
--
search term is guitar god magic metal
new has 140 matches
new_elapsed: 0.66281390190125
--
search term is mott the hoople
new has 0 matches
new_elapsed: 0.0023038387298584
--
```

It is worth noting that "the" is included in the stop words and **innodb_ft_min_token_size** is set to 3.

Why is this happening? I worry that "and" might be interpreted as some kind of operator by the full-text search engine. These longer search terms are unacceptable for my application. I am tempted to either a) add "and" to my stopwords or b) filter the word and from any search string in my code but I worry that this slow query problem might be triggered by other words.

EDIT: Per Raymond comments, I have posted some explain statements here. I'm focusing on this one of the inner queries because it is *very slow* all by itself.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT c.id_code AS c_i, c.title AS c_t, c.seo_title, AVG(MATCH(ts.task) AGAINST ('pig and whistle' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)) * 3 AS score, 'q_ts' AS qid
FROM tasks ts, careers c
WHERE ts.id_code = c.id_code
    AND MATCH(ts.task) AGAINST ('pig and whistle' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
GROUP BY c_i
```

This yields:

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra   
1   SIMPLE  ts  fulltext    id_code,task    task    0   NULL    1   Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  c   ALL     id_code     NULL    NULL    NULL    1110    Using where
```

Raymond suggested the query was not ANSI-compliant so I modified the group by clause to add the additional columns and tried again. It's still slow:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT c.id_code AS c_i, c.title AS c_t, c.seo_title, AVG(MATCH(ts.task) AGAINST ('pig and whistle' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)) * 3 AS score, 'q_ts' AS qid
FROM tasks ts, careers c
WHERE ts.id_code = c.id_code
    AND MATCH(ts.task) AGAINST ('pig and whistle' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
GROUP BY c_i, c_t, seo_title
```

The explain output is identical.

If I explain the entire query (with the UNION statements et. al) I get a more elaborate result:

```
id  select_type         table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra   
1   PRIMARY         <derived2>  ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    3332    Using temporary; Using filesort
2   DERIVED         c   fulltext    title   title   0   NULL    1   Using where
3   UNION       ts  fulltext    id_code,task    task    0   NULL    1   Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
3   UNION       c   ALL     id_code     NULL    NULL    NULL    1110    Using where
4   UNION       oat     fulltext    id_code,alternate_title     alternate_title     0   NULL    1   Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
4   UNION       c   ALL     id_code     NULL    NULL    NULL    1110    Using where
5   UNION       od  fulltext    PRIMARY,description     description     0   NULL    1   Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
5   UNION       c   ALL     id_code     NULL    NULL    NULL    1110    Using where
NULL    UNION RESULT        <union2,3,4,5>  ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    Using temporary
```

EDIT 2: Raymond also asked for the table definitions. Here they are:

```
CREATE TABLE `careers` (
 `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `id_code` varchar(12) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `title` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `title_singular` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `seo_title` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
 `cat_id` varchar(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `occ_code` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
 `forum_id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `id_code` (`id_code`),
 KEY `cat_id` (`cat_id`),
 KEY `forum_id` (`forum_id`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `title` (`title`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1111 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1


CREATE TABLE `tasks` (
 `id_code` char(10) NOT NULL,
 `task_id` decimal(8,0) NOT NULL,
 `task` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
 `task_type` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
 `incumbents_responding` decimal(4,0) DEFAULT NULL,
 `date_updated` date NOT NULL,
 `domain_source` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`task_id`),
 KEY `id_code` (`id_code`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `task` (`task`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8


CREATE TABLE `other_titles` (
 `id_code` char(10) NOT NULL,
 `alternate_title` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
 `short_title` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
 `sources` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 KEY `id_code` (`id_code`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `alternate_title` (`alternate_title`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8



CREATE TABLE `other_data` (
 `id_code` char(10) NOT NULL,
 `title` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
 `description` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id_code`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `description` (`description`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Side note: `SELECT c.id_code AS c_i, c.title AS c_t, c.seo_title, AVG(MATCH(ts.task) AGAINST (:clean_string IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)) * :career_task_statement_factor AS score, 'q_ts' AS qid ... GROUP BY c_i` does not look like a valid ANSI SQL query to me it is misusing MySQL GROUP BY feature ( can cause onrelated data in the select column which arn't in the group by ) or MySQL GROUP BY functional dependency where the results are ok but the query isn't really "ok"

Comment: @RaymondNijland you'll note that there's a 1-to-1 correspondence between c_i, c_t, and c.seo_title and the last element uses a group by function [AVG](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg)

Comment: "you'll note that there's a 1-to-1 correspondence between c_i, c_t, and c.seo_title and the last element uses a group by function" i mean the inner queries @AVG  that isn't a valid way of using GROUP BY simple as that

Comment: @RaymondNijland you will also notice, if you actually read my original post, that the word "and" is *not* among the stopwords defined for mysql. If "and" was removed from the query as a stopword or one that was too short, the query would run extremely quickly.

Comment: "you will also notice, if you actually read my original post, that the word "and" is not among the stopwords defined for mysql. " Yes sure i was to busy writing the comment about the side note that i didn't read the last part

Comment: @RaymondNijland AVG is used as a group_by operator *in the inner queries.* The outer query uses a different group by operator, [SUM](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum). I dispute that the query is invalid for MySQL. Its ANSI validity is irrelevant for my purposes here.  Also, thank you for your reponse, but the queries run fine if the word "and" is not present.

Comment: " I dispute that the query is invalid for MySQL. It's ANSI validity is irrelevant. " Ok if you want the chance off unrelated data that's your call.. Back on topic run a `EXPLAIN <query>` to see how the optimizer is handling things.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179713/discussion-between-s-imp-and-raymond-nijland).

Comment: @RaymondNijland is there some way to inspect the contents of the full text search? Since "and" is not among the stopwords and because it probably appears in a LOT of entries, I expect this might be the issue? I would like to try a query that uses the second- and third-most popular words.

Comment: What happens if you search for "video and games"?

Comment: @Nick slow AF! And you don't need the whole giant query to run all you need is `SELECT c.id_code AS c_i, c.title AS c_t, c.seo_title, AVG(MATCH(ts.task) AGAINST ('video and games' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)) * 3 AS score, 'q_ts' AS qid
FROM tasks ts, careers c
WHERE ts.id_code = c.id_code
    AND MATCH(ts.task) AGAINST ('video and games' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
GROUP BY c_i` and it takes about 8 seconds. I want to say this is because 'and' is an extremely common word, which yields lots of temporary table data to be munged? Is there some way to inspect fulltext index words by frequency?

Comment: Well when you do a full-text search in natural language mode it has to sort the results by relevancy so **any** value that has the word "and" in it will have relevance to your query and will need to be sorted into the results.

Comment: @Nick I'm starting to think along those lines as well. "And" is an extremely common word and IMHO adds nothing to any real-world search while dramatically inflating the number of matches. What confuses me is that it's SO slow and also the word "and" is not in the stopwords despite being [one of the most common words in the entire english language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_common_words_in_English). I'd love to get a good technical reason for this so I can understand *why* it happens.

Comment: I'm afraid that's beyond my depth of knowledge... But you could create your own stopword table specific to this table and include "and" in it. See [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-stopwords.html) and [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_ft_user_stopword_table)